# Inserting base64 into mongodb: Syntax error Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: mongodb, base64

I'm running into a problem storing base64 data into a mongo database.

I'm using `mongo < /file/path/file.js` to execute the command

It works fine when I substitute the img data with anything else. It doesn't seem to like something about the base64 string and returns the `Syntax error Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

The file.js can be found [here](https://github.com/heliumface770/3dpData/blob/master/script.js) since it's far too long to post

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#shell):

> The mongo shell prompt has a limit of 4095 codepoints for each line. If you enter a line with more than 4095 codepoints, the shell will truncate it.

Apparently your script exceeds the limit. Try using [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) istead of the script:

**img.json**

```
{"name": "test", "img": "data:image/png;base64,..."}
```

**bash**

```sh
mongoimport -d imagesdb -c images img.json
```